# Two output channels to represent three states

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a convolutional, fully connected network. which should evaluate to one of three states: "A", "B" or "neither A nor B."

My training labels are setup with two dimensions (or "pins"), like so:

```
if condition_a_active:
    labels.append([1.0, 0.0])
elif condition_b_active:
    labels.append([0.0, 1.0])
else: # both conditions A and B inactive
    labels.append([0.0, 0.0])
```

I know that if I keep *three* different output dimensions (and thus an extra output "pin" for *both condition A and condition B inactive*) I can evaluate my network with this code:

```
result = tf.equal(tf.argmax(labels, 1), tf.argmax(prediction_op, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(result, tf.float32))
```

Can I do the same with two "pins," where say *both below .5* would mean *both A and B inactive*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you need to create some extra tensors, something like this:

```
# creates 'both inactive' ground truth flag tensor
both_inactive_gt = tf.cast( 1.0 - tf.reduce_sum( labels, 1 ), tf.bool ) 

threshold = 0.5 # whatever threshold you want to use

# two steps to create prediction flag tensor
# First: -2, -1, 0, 1, or 2 : only -2 is interesting for us
both_inactive_pred_0 = tf.reduce_sum( tf.sign( prediction_op - threshold ), 1 )
# Second: True for 'both inactive' and False otherwise
both_inactive_pred = tf.cast( - tf.sign( both_inactive_pred_0 + 1.5 ), tf.bool ) 

# now tie it all together
result = tf.logical_or(
    tf.logical_and( both_inactive_gt, both_inactive_pred ),
    tf.logical_and( tf.logical_not( both_inactive_gt ),
                    tf.equal(tf.argmax(labels, 1), tf.argmax(prediction_op, 1 ) ) )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried `tf.reduce_mean(1 - tf.abs(labels-prediction_op))`, might that work? My thought was that it would yield a float between `0==terribly bad` to `1==perfect match`.

Comment: Well that depends what behavior you want from labels `[ 1, 0 ]` prediction `[ 0.4, 0.6 ]`? My guess would be that would be zero accuracy for you but you get 0.4 from this formula. Also, I thought you wanted to threshold the prediction for case 'both inactive' but pick the highest probability in other cases. So for the original specs you posted, this it not enough. You're free to change your specs, though, and it might work as well. Certainly, much simpler. :)

Answer (score 0):

For canonical reference I'm adding this solution for those who prefer an explicitly arithmetic solution.

```
element_result = tf.cast(1.5 - tf.abs(label-prediction), tf.int8) # 1.5 due to floor rounding
row_result = tf.reduce_all(tf.cast(element_result, tf.bool), axis=1) # AND 'em together
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(row_result, tf.float32))
```